# counting ways for sum with maximums on variables

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If $a < 3$ and $b < 4$ and $a, b, c, d \geq 0$, how may different combinations are there for $a + b + c + d = 10$?

I've tried star and bar method but had no luck. How can I approach this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  In this case, you could show your calculation for the number of nonnegative integer solutions of the equation $a + b + c + d = 10$ so that we can check that calculation.  I suspect that you are stuck on how to handle the restrictions, but you should explicitly state that so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and non-negative. And even though you mentioned combination, I assume $a=b=c=0,d=10$ is different from $a=b=d=0, c=10$. It very easy to tune it if you intended otherwise.

This problem can be most elegantly solved with additive number theory method. As I don't know it (yet :), I will approach it with a computer algorithm method called dynamic programming.

Define $p(n,m)$ the number of ways of partitioning an integer $n$ into sum of $m$ non-negative integers. $p(n,m)$ can be arranged into a $n\times m$ matrix/grid to minimize counting work.

So our problem becomes evaluation of $p(10,4)$ with the restriction $a<3, b<4$.

$p(10,4)=p(10,3)+p(9,3)+p(8,3)$ RHS, assign $0,1,2$ to $a$ respectively and pass to next level

$p(10,3)=p(10,2)+p(9,2)+p(8,2)+p(7,2)$ RHS, assign $0,1,2,3$ to $b$ respectively and pass to next level；

$p(9,3)=p(9,2)+p(8,2)+p(7,2)+p(6,2)$ RHS, assign $0,1,2,3$ to $b$ respectively and pass to next level;

(Note: $p(9,2),p(8,2)$ etc appears on RHS multiple times, the intention of a dynamic programming is to process these repetition only once.)

$\cdots$

$p(10,2)=p(10,1)+p(9,1)+\cdots+p(0,1)=11$, assign $0,1,2,\cdots,10$ to $c$ respectively. And each represent a final scheme, so we have $11$ ways...

Make a table and do it manually. It's a good educational experience to understand dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible values $(0,1,2)$ for $a$ and four $(0,1,2,3)$ for $b$.  Thus there are twelve settings for $a$ and $b$.  For each setting, there are $10 - (a+b) + 1$ possible values for $c$.  Then $d$ is constrained and fixed.

So go through the $12$ settings for $a$ and $b$, and for each, add up the number of settings for $c$.  And you're done!

For instance:  $a=0, b=0$ leads to $11$ possible values for $c$ $(0, 1, \ldots, 10)$ and then $d$ is constrained.

I get $102$.